# What is happening here while post/pre decrementing a char variable in C

Tags: c, char

I was solving some multiple choice C codes from a book. Two of the questions involve pre decrementing, post decrementing a char variable initialised at 0. The output for both these is very different. I dont understand whats going on there.

Code 1

```
char i=0;
do
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}while(i--);
return 0;
```

The output for this snippet is 0.

Code 2

```
char i=0;
do
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}while(--i);
return 0;
```

The output is for this one is
0,-1,-2,.....-128,127,126,......1 .

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

At both code `while` loop checking `i==0` or not. If `i!=0`it will keep going on.

At first code value of `i` initially `0`. So after printing `0` it checks `i==0` or not. if `i==0` it will break the loop or keep going on by decrementing `i`. So in code 1 post decrementing used. **check value first then decrements the value**.

At second code value of `i` initially `0`. So after printing `0` it decrements `i` then it checks if `i==0` or not. it is pre decrement. **decrement value first then check.**

Here, `i` is `char` which size is `1 byte` and range `-128 to 127`. So after decrementing value `0` to `-1` it keep decrementing until it goes to `0` and exit the loop by printing 0,-1,...,-128,127...1 .

Answer (score 1):

- Initial value of `i` is `0`.
- In Code 1, first `while` check happens in which the value of `i` (`= 0`) is used and then `i` is decremented because it is postfix decrement.  So it exits `while` after printing `0`.
- In Code 2, because it is prefix decrement, `i` is decremented first and its value (`= -1`) is used when the `while` check is performed.  Here it exits after printing the entire range of values a `signed char` can hold because it becomes `0` at the end only.

Answer (score 1):

Code 1

```
char i=0;
do
{
    printf("%d ",i);    // print o
}while(i--);           //check i = 0, means false, loop ends, then increment i
 return 0;
```

Code 2

```
char i=0;
do
{
    printf("%d ",i);     //print 0
}while(--i);             //decrement i, check i=-1, means true, next cycle, loop until i = 0 which means false
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `i--` and `--i` are **expressions**. An expression is (part of) a statement **that can yield a value**. As per definition, the pre-increment version increments first, then yields the value. For the post-increment version it is the other way round.

This is completely independent of whether the expression is used in a  `while` statement or elsewhere. However, when using such expressions, you need to be aware of [operator precendence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).